# Как ввести массив с клавиатуры через пробел, указав его размер

Tags: python

В первой строке ввести размер массива
Во второй строке ввести элементы массива в одну строку через пробел

Comment: `input(); li = input().split()`? Мне просто не очень понятно, зачем знать размер массива. Может быть введено больше данных, чем нужно?

Comment: требуется в задании https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=47982&chapterid=229#1

Answer (score 1):

```py
n = int(input("Количество элементов > "))

def inp(count):
  if count < 1:
    return []
  s = input("Введите элементы:\n> ").split()
  if len(s) != count:
    print("Неверное количество элементов.")
    return inp(count)
  return s

li = inp(n)
print(li)
```

Результат:

```
Количество элементов > 5
Введите элементы:
> Привет, мир
Неверное количество элементов.
Введите элементы:
> Привет, о дивный мир
Неверное количество элементов.
Введите элементы:
> Привет, о дивный новый мир
['Привет,', 'о', 'дивный', 'новый', 'мир']
```